# Composing a request using Proxy manager

Tags: http, curl, fiddler

I am making a proof of concept for a project.
I have a GPS provider. I need to make a GET request to their servers, and my task is to make a first step and get some data. 
Instructions they gave are given using c-URL. How do I make a fiddler request based on it?

c-URL:

> curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -u 653638dc733afce75130303fe6e6010f63768af0:X http://XXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXX/api/v2/:api_endpoint
>     curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -u 653638dc733afce75130303fe6e6010f63768af0:X http://XXXXX.XXXXXXX.XX/api/v2/:api_endpoint -d '{JSON data}'

I am using Windows, and If I paste this to GitBash(has c-URL) it works. I need to make this an AJAX request. I am using Fiddler to get it to work, then I can make AJAX easy.

This is the small instruction on the provider:

> Authentication is managed using HTTP authentication. Every request must include the Authorization HTTP header. Use your API token as the username, and X (or some otherwise bogus text) as the password (only the API token is used for authenticating API requests)
>   Token can be generated and revocated from the web interface of the WebServices.

How do I construct a GET header base on this data

Comment: The simplest approach here would be to just make the request via CURL pointed at Fiddler; then you'll see exactly what the request is in HTTP without any CURL-specific syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I managed so far, I wonder is it correct:

> User-Agent: Fiddler
>   Host: XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXX
>   Accept: application/json
>   Content-type: application/json
>   -u 653638dc733afce75130303fe6e6010f63768af0: 
>   X: rwerwe